# java : Strange Structure to form the Request Object

Tags: java

For sending the request , i need to send the UserlistServiceRequest 
Once i set the Data inside the User Object .
Please let me know how can i  create the UserlistServiceRequest with this structure ??

// Created the User Object here

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    User user1 = new User();
        User user2= new User();

                user1.name = "ABC";
        user1.age = "28";
        user2.name = "XYZ";
        user2.age = "38";


}
```

**UserlistServiceRequest.java**

```
public class UserlistServiceRequest {

   private String            UserlistId;
   private Userlists        Userlists;

   public void setUserlists(Userlists Userlists)
   {
      this.Userlists = Userlists;
   }

   public Userlists getUserlists()
   {
      return Userlists;
   }

   public void setUserlistId(String UserlistId)
   {
      this.UserlistId = UserlistId;
   }

   public String getUserlistId()
   {
      return UserlistId;
   }

}
```

**Userlists.java**

```
public class Userlists implements Serializable {


    private Userlist[] Userlist;
    public Userlist[] getUserlist() {
        return Userlist;
    }
    public void setUserlist(Userlist[] Userlist) {
        this.Userlist = Userlist;
    }

}
```

**Userlist.java**

```
public class Userlist implements Serializable
{

   private UserlistItem[]   UserlistItem;


   public UserlistItem[] getUserlistItem()
   {
      return UserlistItem;
   }

   public void setUserlistItem(UserlistItem[] UserlistItem)
   {
      this.UserlistItem = UserlistItem;
   }
}
```

**UserlistItem.java**

```
public class UserlistItem implements java.io.Serializable {


    private User user; 

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}
```

**User.java**

```
  public class User implements Serializable
    {

       private String            name ;

     public String getName()
       {
          return name;
       }

       public void setSym(String name)
       {
          this.name = name;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure is really made much complex unnecessarily.

Why you need to create UserList`/`UserListServiceRequestList`and so..?? Just User class and`UserServiceRequest` is enough to serve your purpose.You can then make List of respective objects when needed.

Comment: This is an existing structure , and i need to follow that , could anybody please help , i was unable to do it ,  so i posted here